# correct syntax for this code in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having troubles trying the make this code works with razor

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <ul>@createSubastaContainer(Model.ElementAt(i))
    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        </ul>
    }
}
```

What I want if the element it's a multiply of 5 print the end of the `</ul>`

What's wrong with my code because it's printing the `</ul>` all the time and also the expression itself

**UPDATE**

Base on the red @marteljn answer it when i made the change throws exception

`The for block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place a `@` before your `if` statement, so `@if (...` but as a side note, this would be a great opportunity to create an extension method that extends the HtmlHelper class.

**Edit**

It is picking up a mismatched tag.  The razor view engine enforces HTML compliance when it comes to mismatched tag.  So what you can do is replace your tags with `@Html.Raw("<ul>")` and `@Html.Raw("</ul>")`.

Comment: I edited my answer... a second time... Html.Raw is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)  
{
    <ul>@createSubastaContainer(Model.ElementAt(i))
    @if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        <text></ul></text>
    }
}
```

or this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)  
{
    <ul>@createSubastaContainer(Model.ElementAt(i))
    @if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        @: </ul>
    }
}
```

Here you have a great post about all this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) 
{ 
    @:<ul>
    createSubastaContainer(Model.ElementAt(i)) 
    if (i % 5 == 0) 
    { 
        @:</ul> 
    } 
}
```